# GET api is working fine on chrome but not in IE11

Tags: javascript, java, angular, reactjs, spring-boot

When I load my application, v1/validsColumns endpoint call.
Endpoint working fine with chrome but failed in IE11 with 400.

IN IE

```
v1/validCopyColumns?category=RFQ&columns=["ACTION_STATUS","ACTION_PRIORITY"]&t=1566560052502    
HTTPS    
GET    
400
```

IN Chrome

```
v1/validCopyColumns?category=RFQ&columns=[%22ACTION_STATUS%22,%22ACTION_PRIORITY%22]&t=1566559916624
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 10.101.11.67:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

and spring boot log

```
2019-09-10 00:04:30 [http-nio-8905-exec-53] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:476) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:687) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
```

Please help me to understand issue will be from frontend or backend?
How i will fix it?

Comment: no front end code? How can we help?

Comment: Maybe it's CORS related? Maybe Cross Origin Requests are enabled for Chrome but not for IE

Comment: Why does this have both angular and react tags?

Comment: you can see the difference in the request right? IE11 isn't "escaping" the quotes

Answer (score 0):

URL was not encoded properly if you observe the request URL in IE.